# Get Session Id in Selenium Webdriver returns Alphanumeric format how can I keep the original format?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies

I am trying to get the session Id in my selenium webdriver Test script,and recall it with my driver.
the scenario is checking if logged in user has more than one project associated with or not.If I get the session Id and recall it in a different URL I can get a list of projects and assert if it's only one project in the Json response or there are multiple projects, and according to this result I will have different approach to continue the test.
 what is returned is : "c5f6c1b85d4e1daf0be07996ce1c2599" and what I need to use in that recall URL is : sessionID%3D**99f88e3d-7f2e-4982-ad44-96cfc4660fbc**

Is there any way I can keep the original format when I do a get session ?
If my question is very general please let me know to add more detail.However this is the script I use to launch my app and login :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   //Call method to launch and resize the Chrome window 
    WebDriver driver = LoginAndResize.launchChrome();

    //login as an admin User;
     try {
            WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1013-inputEl"));
            UserName.sendKeys("XXXXXXXXXX");
            WebElement Pass = driver.findElement(By.id("textfield-1015-inputEl"));
            Pass.sendKeys("1xxxxxx1");
            WebElement LoginKey = driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton-btnEl"));
            LoginKey.click(); 
            SessionId sessionId = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getSessionId();               
            System.out.println(sessionId);
            } finally {}
```